# Expected number of times a mosquito bites (per night)?

Tags: entomology, mosquitoes

Imagine you are sleeping alone in your bedroom and there is a (female) mosquito in the room wanting to feed on your blood. I read [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/13/science/13qna.html) the mosquito will try to keep biting and feeding on you until its belly is full.

**Question:** *What are the expected number of times the mosquito will bite you if you do not actively avoid it?* (For example, in the case you were sleeping). However, I imagine this might vary with the mosquito species.

In particular, I am thinking about strategies aiming for minimizing the number of the mosquito bites: would it be feasible to let the mosquito bite you once and suck your blood until becoming fully feed?

Comment: as far as i know mosquitos bite only once,if they get disturbed before they are full they will not bite again.

Comment: @trondhansen Best to answer in a supported answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @BryanKrause i know too little about mosquitos to make an answer,my comment is more an asumption about mosquitos not taking the risk again if they got some blood the fist time.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+times+do+moskitoes+bite There is no limit to the number of mosquito bites one of the insects can inflict. A female mosquito will continue to bite and feed on blood until she is full. After they have consumed enough blood, the mosquito will rest for a couple of days (usually between 2-3) before laying her eggs.

Comment: @com.prehensible That is not the answer to my question. The number of times a mosquito bites a sleeping person (or a person actively not avoiding the bites) will typically follow some distribution; I am asking about the expected value of this distribution (and possibly its standard deviation). However, I understand probably this has not been studied.

Comment: There are many variables to your question then... 3000 species of mosquitoes, dozens commonly drink human blood. A sleeping person, what are they wearing, what are they covering up? how much the person stirs if they are bitten? What time of night bitten,,, deep sleep? That is the science you want, human physiology of stirring in response to bites. mostly she will find a spot with enough bloodflow to fill up, and only sting  once. thats why no research is that general.

Comment: quote:... In particular, I am thinking about strategies aiming for minimizing the number of the mosquito bites: would it be feasible to let the mosquito bite you once and suck your blood until becoming fully feed? ... it does answer your question in particular.

Comment: @com.prehensible *mostly she will find a spot with enough bloodflow to fill up, and only sting once.* could you provide some source for this? (And maybe write it in an answer)

Comment: No. I just linked the NYT science post on it, check the google search to find references yourself: It is also possible that some blood types are not as easily thinned by the anticoagulant in the mosquito’s saliva, so the mosquito has to make more tries to get a satisfying meal. Another factor may be...

Answer (score 1):

From a couple of species (Culex quinquefasciatus, Anopheles gambiae) I rear and feed in laboratory, I can tell that if the female is not disturbed, she will bite only once, untill her belly if full, as you said.

So the best to minimize the number of bites (and to get rid of the disturbing mosquito noise while trying to sleep!!) is to let you be bitten once to be alright the rest of the night. This is easier to say than to achieve, but this should be the best, provided on:

- filling all the largest holes of your room to be sure that mosquitoes cannot enter (use mosquito nets!)
- switching off the main light to encourage the mosquito to come quickly (for night species). The mosquito will be attracted to your breath, then to your heat at close proximity.
- offer the back of your arm where the skin is the thinnest, that may be less scratchy
- after the bite, you can put some water gently on the bite to avoid any body response against [mosquito saliva](https://endmosquitoes.com/why-do-mosquito-bites-itch-stop-scratching-tips/), but don't touch it otherwise you may elicit  the scratching feeling.

Then, you should sleep peacefully for the rest of the night, except if a mosquito gang is around.

Comment: Nice answer haha Though I tend to go with the more destructive alternative: eradicate the little monster (at the cost of losing my sleep).